# In Rails 5, how to inject the current_user.id into a controller#create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 to create an API. My controller looks like the following:

```
  ....
  def create
    @user_position = UserPosition.create(user_position_params)
    json_response(@user_position)
  end

private

  def user_position_params
    params.require(:user_position).permit(:job_title_id)
  end

  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end

end
```

In the create method, how can I add `:user_id => current_user.id` With Rails 5, should this be in the user_position_params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `create` would persist the new record with the `user_position_params` on the database once is "executed", you could use instead `new` to set a new `UserPosition` instance and then to set the `user_id` as the `id` from the `current_user`, after this, you can `save` it, try with:

```
@user_position = UserPosition.new(user_position_params)
@user_position.user_id = current_user.id
@user_position.save
```

Comment: I've updated the answer @AnApprentice, using `save` instead `create`.

Comment: If you have your associations set up it's just `current_user.user_positions.create(user_position_params)`